Redis + bull server not working when deployed to render
So I created a simple express server that uses bull and Redis to offload tasks and run them even if the user leaves the page.
The api works perfectly on my machine but when i upload  it to render (with paid plan) it does not work and i sometimes get this error in the logs:
Error adding job to queue: MaxRetriesPerRequestError: Reached the max retries per request limit (which is 20). Refer to "maxRetriesPerRequest" option for details.

I created a smaller api to check the error and it behaves the same as the big api, and this is the code
const express = require('express'); // Import Express
const Queue = require('bull'); // Import Bull
const redis = require('redis'); // Import Redis

// Create Redis client
const redisClient = redis.createClient({
    host: '',
    port: '',
});

redisClient.on('error', (err) => {
    console.error('Redis error:', err);
});

// Initialize Bull queue
const queue = new Queue('jobQueue', {
    redis: {
        config here
    },
});

  
  let jobResults = []; // Array to store results of jobs
  
  // Function to execute a random task and store the result
  const executeRandomFunction = () => {
    const results = [];
    const functions = [
      () => results.push("Random number: " + Math.random()),
      () => results.push("Current time: " + new Date().toLocaleTimeString()),
      () => results.push("Random boolean: " + (Math.random() > 0.5)),
    ];
  
    // Pick a random function and execute it
    const randomFunc = functions[Math.floor(Math.random() * functions.length)];
    randomFunc();
  
    return results.join(' | ');
  };
  
  // Define the job processor
  queue.process('extractTextJob', async (job) => {
    console.log(`Processing job ${job.id}`);
    const result = executeRandomFunction();
    jobResults.push(result); // Store result in the array
    return Promise.resolve();
  });
  
  // Add a job to the queue every 5 seconds
  setInterval(async () => {
    await queue.add('extractTextJob',{}); // You can pass data to jobs if needed
    console.log('Job added to queue');
  }, 5000);
  
  console.log('Queue and processor set up. Jobs will be added every 5 seconds.');
  
  // Set up Express server
  const app = express();
  const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
  
  app.use(express.json());
  
  // Route to get job results
  app.get('/results', (req, res) => {
    res.json({ results: jobResults });
  });
  
  app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
  });

Does anyone have any ideas why it does not work?
